# Find how many different ways you can wallpaper 8 rooms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

What are the steps in the solving the problem below. Do you use the product rule, summation rule, or both?

In how many ways you can wallpaper the same $8$ rooms with $12$ types of wallpaper?

Comment: Can you reuse the same wallpaper for different rooms? If so, what @Rainier said is correct.

Comment: Repetition allowed: $12^8$. Repetition not allowed: $\frac{12!}{(12-8)!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you can reuse a wallpaper. Then for each room there are 12 possibilities, so by the product rule there are $12^8$ possibilities in total.

Comment: Then for this question the answer would be $2^8$?
In how many ways you can paint 8 rooms, if you have two types of paint: black and blue?(Mixing the paint is not allowed).

Comment: @Csci319 yes, exactly, given that repetition is allowed.

Comment: if it does not say then can you assume that it is allowed? Is there some general rule?

Comment: @Csci319 Yes, but you need to check each problem individually.

Comment: When the problem says no mixing paints I can still assume repetition is allowed, right?
So the formula for this type of problem would be $W^R$ W is wallpaper and R is room

Comment: That's right @Csci319

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21149/discussion-between-csci319-and-rainier-van-es).

Answer (score 2):

Repetition allowed: $12\cdot12\cdot12\cdot12\cdot12\cdot12\cdot12\cdot12=12^8$.

Repetition not allowed: $12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5=\frac{12!}{(12-8)!}$.